# How do we handle Windows 10 (Threshold 2) Questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, windows-10

So the release of Windows 10 on July 29th 2015 was known as Threshold 1.  The current release is the Threshold 2 build.  It was released on November 12th 2015.

Threshold 2 bring several specific enhancements to Windows 10.  Some of those things are not possible in build 10240 (Threshold 1).  An example of this would be installing Windows 10 with a Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 license key.

There are some other generic improvements that also come with Threshold 2.  In the end there are several major and minor things that make these two builds different enough that warrant separate tags.

I feel this is an important to decide, because when the next update, `Windows Anniversary Edition` is released Microsoft Edge will support extensions.  So any answers to questions about Microsoft Edge today might not apply to a user running Windows 10 `Windows Anniversary Edition` in a year.

It will be possible to defer `Windows Anniversary Edition` and Threshold 2 for a period of time on Windows 10 Professional and Windows 10 Enterprise installation.  So although these updates are "required" there is still a legitimate need to separate questions even if we are only applying these changes to old questions asked before these updates are released.

So how do we separate Windows 10 questions?  This same question can be applied to the next updates `Windows Anniversary Edition` in 2016.  Looking forward the changes between these builds, will be as different as, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 are to one another.

As somebody who performed the update to Threshold 2 I can say to the end user, it appears that Windows 10 is being installed again, so this is a major update.  *This isn't as simple as installing a service pack.*

So my suggestion would be to rename the current `Windows-10` tag to `Windows-10-TH1` and update the description.  Now that Threshold 2 is officialy released we should create a `Windows-10-TH2`tag and update the description to indicate the difference between the two releases.  I feel this would would be similar to the `Office-XXXX` tags we have currently.

Below is a screenshot of the next Windows Insider branch (RS1_Release) which is believed to be the `Windows Anniversary Edition` aka the `Redstone` branch.

[image]

Other Information:

`Threshold 2` is known as the Fall Update which will be reported as `Windows 10 Version 1511` (for 2015 November) and and likely be the 10586.3 build.

Comment: There are some specific questions where the distinction will be important, but I've got to wonder whether tag misuse would be a bigger problem overall.  The OP can always specify the version in the question.  Too much granularity makes it harder for those people who want to follow subject tags.

Comment: That question is a good example.  The average user isn't going to know one Threshold from another or build numbers, so usage of the tag is likely to be spotty and unreliable.

Comment: Maybe the answer is to wait for a sample of questions to come in and judge from that how well the tag is likely to be used.  Information-based decision making.  :-)

Comment: Looks like someone already created and started using [tag:windows-10-v1511] - and that seems to be the new official versioning scheme from MS. So if we do end up keeping the split tags then that might be better than TH2..?

Comment: I feel like if the user is knowledgeable enough to know the difference, they'll say it. Else, if they don't know, they'll pick a tag at random either TH1 or 2. 'How do we handle it' to me is by doing nothing but being diligent in asking for build numbers in the comments of questions that are ambiguous.

Comment: @Ramhound Out of the two, I would certainly prefer the version number - that is what appears in the Version field in system info. Also "Fall Update" doesn't make much sense for those of us in the Southern hemisphere - it's Spring right now! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistency would be that we treat these the same way as we would [windows8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows8) and [windows8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows8.1) and have a new tag for each major(ish) version.

What to name those tags though is the question.  [windows10-th1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows10-th1) and [windows10-th2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows10-th2) lacks a certain *je ne sais quoi* as a tag, but as Microsoft isn't naming them something more relevant such as SP1 or 10.1 then it's the best we can really do. If the question is relevant to all versions then the base [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) tag would be preferred.

I had been hoping that these would sound a lot more like real releases than minor feature packs.

Comment: Users don't even know the difference between if it's a problem of 8.1 or 8, does anyone really expect they would use the correct tag? Or worse, would anyone expect there would be users that will waste their time trying to figure out which tag is appropriated? This only would reduce the visibility of the questions, without any marginal gain.

Comment: I explained the benefits did you even read my question?

Comment: @Ramhound it reads as: I want a new shinny tag. Bring hard data. Its only 2 new questions/day on the windows-10 tag, hardly any traffic at all.

Comment: Sure;  Lets not do anything.  Put our heads in the sand.  Whatever.  I am done with this community.  3000 questions in a year about Windows 10 is obviously nothing

Answer (score 1):

Aren't they all using Windows 10 anyways? Why must we use the *reductio ad absurdum* with tags when there isn't any actual gain for asker and answerers? People can't even tell whenever their question is applicable to only one or another version, nor should we hope they know, which would just put more pressure on knowledgeable to fix the tagging (or at least, try to), without any actual benefit of such *chore*. And guess what, they **will not** replace the tags, anyways.

In the end Microsoft will push forward the update/upgrade to all their users for "security reasons" and the point will be reduced moot by then. Answerers should just presume the asker is using any version of it, and answer with the method is applicable for all iterations. I mean, installing software would be the same for years to come, no?

---

Someone created the [windows-10-v1511](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1511), here's the results:

- [Windows 10 Threshold 2 Update Failed - BSOD: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT](https://superuser.com/q/1001713/235569) BSOD that actually had nothing to do with this Windows 10 interaction, but third party software preventing the upgrade to the referred iteration. The user didn't even reached to upgrade his Windows.
- https://superuser.com/questions/1001666/what-does-installed-on-date-in-programs-and-features-mean This is something that it's shared on all versions of Windows 10. Ramhound itself also recognize this. It isn't relevant to what version of Windows 10 you upgrade, all versions will have the same behavior.
- [Windows randomly drops half of connection](https://superuser.com/q/990536/235569) This is very unlikely to be a Windows 10 v1511 specific issue, in fact the issue happens since Windows 7! (I edited the question to remove version specific tags, as it's likely a hardware issue).
- [Icon for Chrome missing after updating Windows-10 to November Update 1511](https://superuser.com/q/1000852/235569) Unlikely a issue specific to this version of Windows, very likely that the icon cache somehow got corrupted. The icon cache is in the same path for Windows [7, 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows) [and 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html).
- [Changing Chrome icon on the tile](https://superuser.com/questions/1001214/) Unlikely a Windows 10 v1511 specific issue. Personalizing icons can (and are) a drag on any version of Windows. Having a single "How can I personalize application icons?" canonical post for all Windows would be recommendable, through in this specific case was another cache staling issue, non specific to this Windows itteraction.
- [Local UNC paths through virtual switch failed after Windows 10 Pro update to 1511](https://superuser.com/q/1001139/235569) Through the update seems to have messed up OP networking, in fact, this can happen with any update of any kind (on any OS), and for OP's specific case, it wasn't even that different solution compared with other Windows 10 installations.
- [Unable to activate Windows 10 with error 0xc004f210](https://superuser.com/q/1000959/235569) Activation issues are never version specific, and given the [most likely assumption](https://superuser.com/questions/1000959/unable-to-activate-windows-10#comment1384654_1000959), the version being v1511 or not doesn't affect how the issue came to be nor it method of solution.

All in all, none of these questions benefits from having an extra tag, and in those cases where it would make sense, the issue isn't even related.

Comment: @Ramhound but, why should we care about them? Windows 10 tag gets at most ~2 questions day, it isn't even overloaded. Futher categorization (or more accurately: just because) doesn't make answerers find questions easier, and as I said before, there's simply no benefit on doing so.

Comment: @Ramhound but, will be impossible with 1511+ builds? No. That's why the [version specific tags] guideline says: I would only use version tags when the question content is irrevocably tied to a specific version of something and can never be relevant to earlier versions or **later versions.** It isn't expected that later versions of Windows 10 not to be able to do this (or do you have insider information?).

Comment: @Ramhound but why should they be separated from the general Windows 10 herd? If I ask the question the answer could be: if you are using X version you can't, unlike people using Y version, which can do it this way. See? **There is less information duplication and all the information is in a single Q&A pair.** Further separation is not needed, is counterproductive. Users shouldn't have to ask several questions for each interaction of any piece of software, that's why there's a bounty reason that reads: The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision **given recent changes.**

Comment: You are right.  It shouldn't be separated.